# Switch Enum in Java in Zookeper

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, apache-zookeeper

I imported Zookeeper from its git repository - master branch (Hence it is supposed to be running). I didn't modify its code yet.

I encounter an unexpected problem with enum:

> Cannot switch on a value of type AuthFastLeaderElection.ToSend.mType. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted

I expect that the problem is with the debugging version so I made sure that all the selected versions are 1.8

A snippet of code where the problem is:

```
static public class ToSend {

    static enum mType {
        crequest, challenge, notification, ack
    }

    ToSend(mType type, long tag, long leader, long zxid, long epoch,
            ServerState state, InetSocketAddress addr) {

        switch (type) {
        case crequest:
            this.type = 0;
            this.tag = tag;
            ....
```

I am using eclipse Luna:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>   Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
>   Build id: 20150219-0600

my java version is up to date:

> java version "1.8.0_112"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)

Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Master is not guaranteed to work. Use a maven dependency instead unless you actually want to work under the hood.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Thank you dear. I just dropped down to 1.7 and it is solved as somebody suggested.

Comment: By the way, is this considered as a bug?!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you I will take your advice into consideration.